# Bootstrap Carousel is overriding my own styles in html

Tags: html, bootstrap-carousel

I am VERY new to html and have very limited skills so please bear with me.

I am trying to put an infinite image carousel with links on the front page of my website. But Bootstrap overrides my web styles. I thought I knew where my styles where( I obviously do not) and tried to add them after the carousel but it did not work.

I need the carousel in a specific place on the page.

I tried putting the carousel in a table or adding    etc.(pretty much anything I could think of) all in vain. Not sure what to do as I am far from being a master code writer......
any help with this would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Always load Bootstraps css before your custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases for bootstrap that I am aware of, Bootstrap styles will not override custom styles if you load your own styles after the bootstrap styles.

correct way:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link-to-boostrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom-styles.css">
</head>
```

incorrect way:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link-to-boostrap.css">
</head>
```

Stylesheets should always be in the header except for very specific circumstances.

If you are putting styles directly on the page in a `<style>` tag you can move them to the external style sheet following these instuctions: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm still not sure what to do. tried to post code to see where i should insert that. (feeling dumb)

Comment: If you're not sure what I mean by the above you should probably take a quick skim through [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp) before getting into something more complicated like bootstrap. Sorry to sound condescending but it'll save you a lot of time in the long run if you have your basics down really solid.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a place on here I can pay someone to fix this problem in the mean time? I need this up and running asap and will have to read the tutorial on my own time when I'm not at work. And you did not sound condescending.Thanks

Comment: Or is there another style of gallery that will fulfill the same function?